# Kinematics equations with calculus what does dv mean?

Tags: calculus, physics

I am trying to solve for kinematics equations using calculus. I am trying to get to this equation:

$$v_t = v_0 + at$$

Which comes from,

$$a = \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
$$ \mathrm{d}v = a \cdot \mathrm{d}t$$
$$ \int_{v_0}^{v_t} \mathrm{d}v = \int_0^{\Delta t} a \cdot \mathrm{d}t$$ 
$$ v_t - v_0 = a \cdot t$$
$$ \boxed{ v_t = v_0 + at}$$

1) What does this mean? **Does it mean that the change in velocity = the acceleration times the change of time?**

Now, when you continue, I also understand the definite integral. I understand why you must have v and v initial and t and 0 (t initial). However, my second question is:

2) **How can you get the antiderivative of something that is not even a derivative? is dv a derivative? I thought the derivative was (dv/dt), not just dv by itself?**

I just don't understand how dv can be anything by itself?

Comment: Hey cer--welcome to MSE! You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions rather than posting an image. You'll find if you do this, your questions will be more well-received and receive better answers

Comment: Please use physics stack exchange

Comment: Would you feel better if the integral were written as $\int 1\,dv$ instead?

Comment: I have up voted as I believe the question at heart is mathematics (FTC) in a physics background and therefore benefits the community.

Answer (score 1):

Answer (1):

Yes, That is what it means.

$v-v_o$(change in velocity)=$a(t-t_o)$(change in time)

In your case $t_o$ is $0$.

Answer (2):

**dv** represents a **very little change in velocity**, i.e. change in velocity when **change in time**$\approx0$

Comment: I disagree with this and would say that $dv$ means nothing by itself.

Comment: @Karl and how can you say that?

Comment: Because I believe that $\int dv$ denotes a limit.

Comment: Just to clarify a little. I think it is important to distinguish antiderivatives and integrals. For integrals you should form a sum then take its limit. I would say that $\Delta v$ is a not necessarily small change in $v$ I am not  a physics expert and conventions may be different.

Comment: @Karl In physics that isn’t as mathematically purist, it’s very advantageous to look at differentials as incremental amounts, especially for students who might also be encountering calculus as the language of physics rather than pulling from years of training in calculus. Also, I believe there’s a whole field about $k$-forms and $\omega^1$ business that could be cited to substantiate this way of thinking.

Comment: Im not sure about the physics stand point but think that using Interchangeable $\Delta v$ and $dv$ is confusing. To be clear I didn't down vote.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it means the change in velocity equals the acceleration times the change in time.

2) $\int\mathrm dv$ can also be written as $\int 1\,\mathrm dv$. Then it becomes more clear that the antiderivative is $v$, since the "derivative" is $1$. That's not the only way to think of it though, so there's no point in writing the extra $1$.

Comment: I would say that $\int 1 dv=v+c$

Comment: @Karl Fair enough, it does. And so does $\int\mathrm dv$. But in a definite integral that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Karl That’s true, but so is nog642’s statement. I don’t think indefinite integrals are used nearly as much in physics as are definite integrals.